# Reading numbers in text file

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python learning how to read and manipulate data in text files.

Lets say I have a text file *grades.txt* :

```
.25 45 67 89
.75 23 45
```

I want to create a program that averages the grades for each line and multiplies that by the weight which is always the first number in each line.

It then should add the weighted total for all of the lines and print a the final grade.

How would I do this if I didn't know the number of grades in a text file or if I had different weights?

Currently I can only do it if I already know how many grades there are going to be.

Code so far:

```
def main():
    file = open("grades.txt", "r")
    for line in file:
        weight, gradeOne, gradeTwo, gradeThree = line.split()
        grade = (int(gradeOne) + int(gradeTwo) + int(gradeThree)/3

        print(float(weight) * grade)

main()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `line.split(' ')` to return a list of grades where the weight is `list[0]`.

Then you can get rid of the weight, and cycle through the list in a for loop.

You add all the grades, then divide by the length of the list of grades.
Don't accidentally include the weight!

Answer (score 3):

After splitting the string, use `map()` to turn each item into a `float`. Use `*` unpacking to assign the first item to `weight`, and the rest to a `list` called `grades`.

```
def main():
    file = open("grades.txt", "r")
    for line in file:
        weight, *grades = map(float, line.split())
        print(weight * sum(grades)/len(grades))

main()
```

You can then use handy functions like `sum()` and `len()` to find the average. `map()`, `float()`, `sum()`, and `len()` are all [Python built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).

Comment: I'd be cheap and do `... = map(float, line.split())`.

Answer (score 0):

This will work in Python 2.7 as well as 3.x.

```
def main():
    total_grade = 0
    with open('grades.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            split = line.split(' ')
            grades = map(int, split[1:])
            line_grade = (sum(grades) / len(grades)) * float(split[0])
            print line_grade
            total_grade += line_grade
    print total_grade

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```